# Accessing a Spreadsheet in Google Drive

Tags: python, google-api, google-sheets

I have a Spreadsheet stored a few directories into my Google Drive that I'd like to access and read with the Google Spreadsheet API using Python. What is the best way to do this? It seems like all of the examples on the Google API website involve documents that are in Google Docs, not Google Drive, and it seems like none of the examples for the Google Drive API involve reading spreadsheets.

Answer (score 2):

You can either use the [Spreadsheets API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/) or [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/) to programmatically access spreadsheets stored on your Drive account.

Answer (score 0):

link = https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/...source = StringIO.StringIO(requests.get(link).content))
data = pd.read_csv(source)